# What is the ⇧ key in Linux?

Tags: sublimetext2

The keyboard shortcuts page for Sublime Text (http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html) lists the ⇧ key for a number of shortcuts in Linux. What is this key, and how do I type it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it refers to Shift, under Lock Caps.

Comment: LOL, I obviously cannot brain today. This the first time I have seen the symbol; before today I have seen it referred to as "Shift" on most pages that discuss keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: yeah it's a little bit  weird, I confused it with the up arrow the first time I saw it ^^

Answer (score 1):

That is the Shift key. You'll usually find two of them, one at either end of the row above the space bar.